# need some help to remove a ' € ' sign with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sorry if this question sounds kind of silly, but i hope someone can help me out :).

I need to remove a euro(€) sign from a span that looks like:

```
<span id='price'>€ 19,99</span>
```

the thing is that i cant change it in the HTML file because these prices are automatically given by this webshop program ...

my first thought was javascript/jquery with a substring or slice method, but i wasnt able to figure out how to do this.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you know how to get the html element and get/modify the text?

Comment: no i dont, i can only change prices in this program, but not the valuta signs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Element.innerText` to get the text and `String.replace` to remove the euro sign:

```js
var price_span = document.getElementById('price');

price_span.innerText = price_span.innerText.replace('€', '');
```

```html
<span id='price'>€ 19,99</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery solution:

```
 $('#price').text( $('#price').text().replace('€', '') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Only with CSS and since the `€` sign is at the beginning of the string, you could use a negative `text-indent` (adjustable, depending on your specific font family ad size)

```css
#price {
  text-indent: -2ch;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span id='price'>€ 19,99</span>
```